# Maximum number of points of intersection of the perpendiculars

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $5$ points in a plane. Let $m$ denote the maximum number of intersections of the perpendiculars drawn from each point to the lines joining the other points. Find $m$. Can I get a visual representation and a little insight on what the question is saying exactly and how to approach it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Max points will be when no three points are collinear . Hope this helps you I find out m as 20.

Comment: For a regular pentagon, no three points are collinear. Yet the perpendiculars from one point to either of the parallel cases of a line through two of the other four will be the same line.